# Unity 3D - Drag and Angular Drag not working

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, 3d, physics, drag

I'm using a boat script for unity 3d in javascript. It almost works perfectly except that the boat will never slow down and turning will cause an infinite turn unless you press the keys in opposite direction. I tried adjusting the mass, drag and angular drag within the inspector for the boat object itself and I even added code for it in the script and it still has no effect. There are no other scripts in the game except a smooth follow camera script also on the boat.

```
 #pragma strict

 var speed : float = 1.0;

 var acceleration : float = 1.0;

 var maxspeed : float = 2.0;

 var minspeed : float = -0.25;

 var heading : float = 0.0;

 var rudder : float = 0.0;

 var rudderDelta : float = 2.0;

 var maxRudder : float = 6.0;

 var bob : float = 0.1;

 var bobFrequency : float = 0.2;

 var rb: Rigidbody;

 private var elapsed : float = 0.0;

 private var seaLevel : float = 0.0;

 private var rudderControl : GameObject;

 private var rudderAngle : float = 0.0;

  function signedSqrt( x : float){

     var r = Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Abs( x ));

     if( x < 0 ){

         return -r;

     } else {

          return r;

     }

 } 


 function Start () {
    rb = GetComponent.<Rigidbody>();
} 


 function Update () {

 rb.angularDrag = 0.8;
 rb.drag = 1;

 // Bobbing

 elapsed += Time.deltaTime;

 transform.position.y = seaLevel + bob * Mathf.Sin(elapsed * bobFrequency * (Mathf.PI * 2));

 // Steering

 rudder += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rudderDelta * Time.deltaTime;

 if( rudder > maxRudder ){

     rudder = maxRudder;

 } else if ( rudder < -maxRudder ){

     rudder = -maxRudder;
 }

 heading = (heading + rudder * Time.deltaTime * signedSqrt(speed)) % 360;

 // transform.Rotate(0, rudder * Time.deltaTime, 0);

 transform.eulerAngles.y = heading;

 transform.eulerAngles.z = -rudder;

 if( rudderControl ){

    rudderAngle = ((-60 * rudder)/maxRudder + heading) % 360;

    //rudderControl.transform.localEulerAngles.y = (70 * rudderAngle)     %     360;

        rudderControl.transform.eulerAngles = Vector3(0, rudderAngle, 0);
     }

     // Sail

     speed += Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * acceleration * Time.deltaTime;

     if( speed > maxspeed ){

             speed = maxspeed;

    }     else if ( speed < minspeed ){

        speed = minspeed;

     }

    transform.Translate(0, 0, speed * Time.deltaTime);

 }

 function Awake (){

     seaLevel = transform.position.y;

     rudderControl = GameObject.Find("rudderControl");

 }
```

I hope it's something simple. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this problem could be caused by the use of

```
transform.Translate(0, 0, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

In my experience, it's best to add force to the rigidbody.

As for the turning issue, do you ever reset the rudder position back to the default? I can't seem to find where this would occur in your code.

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried it out and it and it didn't effect it, but it did help me narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by directly slowing down the speed variable.

```
    if (!Input.GetAxis("Vertical"))
    {

        if (speed > 0 )
            {
                speed -= 0.1f;
                if ( speed < 0 )
                    {
                        speed = 0;
                    }
            }


        if (speed < 0 )
            {
                speed += 0.1f;
                if ( speed > 0 )
                    {
                        speed = 0;
                    }
            }

    }
```

I did the same thing for the rudder.